# 'java' is not recognized as a command, missing a path variable?

Tags: java, environment-variables, command-prompt

I am getting `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` when asking for `java -version` in command prompt.
I have been trying to switch from Java version 17 to 11 and might have deleted a path System variable by accident.

[image: Edit "Path" environment variable window]

Could someone help me understand what I need to do in this scenario? The typical suggestions for java not being a recognized variable are not working.

Comment: Does that java11 path exist?

Comment: From the screenshot you've posted, the first line clearly shows `<JDK11>/bin`. After applying you might have to restart the command prompt session so that variables are reflected. If you are using IDEs like IntelliJ, they require a restart to refresh the variables. FYI Powershell and CMD has a `refreshenv` alias which will update variables in the same session

Comment: @f1sh No, it did not... I had 11.0.14, but in the path, I indicated 11.0.7. Upon fixing this in the path variable, the error is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had java version 11.0.14, but in the path, I indicated 11.0.7. Upon fixing this in the path variable, and restarting command prompt, the error is solved.